# Paste to text file script

Tags: autohotkey

I'd like to use AHK to create the following program:

1. I highlight some text, and hit ctrl+c.
2. I hit the keyboard shortcut, say #c
3. Notepad++ creates a new text file with the content, and promts me to fill in the file name.
4. the txt file is saved in the same location every time, namely /Dropbox/PlainText/Simpletext/

Bonus if I could browse and choose folder in the 4th option.

Is this possible to script?

I do know about click.to

Answer (score 1):

This will create the file, overwriting any existing file you've highlighted, and then open it with Notepad. Replace `notepad.exe` with the path to the Notepad++ exe:

```
#c::
FileSelectFile, FileToSaveTo, S, \Dropbox\PlainText\Simpletext\
Msgbox, %FileToSaveTo%
IfExist, %FileToSaveTo%
  FileDelete, %FileToSaveTo%
FileAppend, %Clipboard%, %FileToSaveTo%
Run, notepad.exe, %FileToSaveTo%
return
```